# I'm trying to make a simple lottery contract with Solidity and React

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity

The file compiles and renders but as soon as i hit the enter lottery button i get this error:

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): *lottery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5*_.default.methods is not a function

I think i am missing something in the deployed contract? but no idea how to fix it.

app.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import web3 from './web3';
import lottery from './lottery';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    manager: '',
    players: [],
    balance: '',
    value: '',
    message: ''
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();
    const players = await lottery.methods.getPlayers().call();
    const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(lottery.options.address);

    this.setState({ manager, players, balance });
  }

  onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts

    this.setState({ message: 'Waiting on transactions success...'});

    await lottery.methods().send({
      from: accounts[0],
      value: web3.utils.toWei(this.state.value, 'ether')
    });

    this.setState({ message: 'You have been entered!'});
  };

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Lottery Contract </h2>
          <p>This contract is managed by {this.state.manager}
            There are currently {this.state.players.length} people entered,
            competing to win {web3.utils.fromWei(this.state.balance, 'ether')} ether!
          </p>

          <hr />

          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <h4>Want to try your luck? </h4>
            <div>
            <label> Amount of ether to enter </label>
            <input
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={event => this.setState({ value: event.target.value })}
              />
            </div>
            <button> Enter </button>
          </form>

          <hr />

          <h1> {this.state.message} </h1>
        </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

lottery.methods() has some problem, try to console.log it. Is it function ?